# custom body message email triggering in Riemann

Tags: clojure, logstash, riemann

I want to trigger a mail with custom body message.  I can parse timestamp in my body, but i want to add the string in my body when i try to add string value in body i'm unable to reproduce it. can anyone help me to resolve it. I'm in very critical implementation.

Please find my sample code below,

```
 (let [email (mailer {:host "cccc"
                            :port 25
                            :user "111111"
                            :pass "111111"
                            :auth "true"
                            :subject (fn [events] "1DD Monitoring - Response time SLA breach")
                            :body (fn [events] 
                       (apply str "Hello Team, now the time is" (:**silo** events) "Thank You!"))
                            :from "xxx@xxxx.com"})]
```

I'm sending value from logstash to riemann in silo field and i want to print silo field value in body

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the handle function that you define for :body, has a wrong syntax. According to the [doc](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/2a64a4dc614ec20f6193a76de4d3821770c4076f/src/riemann/email.clj#L54), you must define a function that takes a sequence of events and return a string. For example:

```
(defn prn-str [& events]
  ...)
```

Comment: 'fn' is there sytax to create a function. 'defn' is convenience function that defines a function, then saves it under a fixed names so it can be called from many places. 'defn' expands to '(def nane-here (fn [] rest of function body here))'

Answer (score 0):

So you have a :**silo** key in your event. But in the :body function, you will have a list of events. (:**silo** events) will be nil.

You can for example get the :**silo** values separated by a comma with:

```
:body (fn [events]
        (str "Hello Team, now the time is "
              (clojure.string/join "," (map #(:**silo** %) events))
               " Thank You!"))
```